# Are there any studies revealing if the typical American diet is deficient in vitamins and minerals?

Tags: diet, micronutrients

Have there been any studies revealing if the typical American diet is deficient in vitamins and minerals?

In other words, if you primarily...

- Eat fruits, vegetables, and grains from pesticide-laden farms with depleted soil
- Eat processed meats from hormone-injected animals that were fed grains from pesticide-laden farms with depleted soil
- Drink pasteurized milk from hormone-injected cows that eat crops from pesticide-laden farms that have depleted soil
- Drink soda pop, energy drinks, or coffee with filtered water

...do people typically still get sufficient vitamins and minerals?

And what if you don't drink that milk, to which Vitamin A is typically added?  Does that make a difference?

Comment: Typical American diet is a useless statistic - It is 'an average' from >300 million people in one of the most diverse societies :) I think a more precise question is needed here.